# How to define a elb-custom-security-policy-ssl-check aws config rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-config

I have the following description of the aws config elb-custom-security-policy-ssl-check rule:

```
    Identifier: ELB_CUSTOM_SECURITY_POLICY_SSL_CHECK
    
    Resource Types: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
    
    Trigger type: Configuration changes
    
    AWS Region: All supported AWS regions except Asia Pacific (Jakarta), Africa (Cape Town), Middle East (UAE), Asia Pacific (Hyderabad), Asia Pacific (Osaka), Asia Pacific (Melbourne), Europe (Milan), AWS GovCloud (US-East), Israel (Tel Aviv), Europe (Spain), Europe (Zurich) Region
    
    Parameters:
    
    sslProtocolsAndCiphers
    Type: String
    Comma separated list of ciphers and protocols.
```

I am creating a terraform configuration for aws config and I have this variable created to pass the **input parameter** for this rule:

```
variable "elb_custom_security_policy_ssl_check" {
  type    = string
  default = "AES128-SHA256,TLSv1.3"
}
```

but I am getting an internal error as the **conformance pack** isn't created, but when I remove that rule it gets created. The proper representation of the **default** values is what I am trying to figure out.

Terraform conformance pack code:

```
resource "aws_config_conformance_pack" "conformancepack" {
  name = "conformancepact"

  template_body = <<EOT

Resources:
  ElbCustomSecurityPolicySslCheck:
    properties:
      ConifigRuleName: elb-custom-security-policy-ssl-check
      InputParameters:
        sslProtocolsAndCiphers: ${var.elb_custom_security_policy_ssl_check}
      Scope:
        ComplianceResourceTypes:
        - AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
      Source:
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: ELB_CUSTOM_SECURITY_POLICY_SSL_CHECK
    Type: AWS::Config::ConfigRule
EOT
}
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the rest of the code to the question?

Comment: Great, can you remove the new line after the start of heredoc?

Comment: Also, have you defined Configuration Recorder with proper IAM permissions?

Comment: yes ... I have and this is the only config rule that prevents the conformance pack from deploying. If I remove it it deploys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the YML created with the heredoc syntax is using a wrong parameter:

```
  template_body = <<EOT

Resources:
  ElbCustomSecurityPolicySslCheck:
    properties:  <------------- This is not the correct property name
      ConfigRuleName: elb-custom-security-policy-ssl-check
      InputParameters:
        sslProtocolsAndCiphers: ${var.elb_custom_security_policy_ssl_check}
      Scope:
        ComplianceResourceTypes:
        - AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
      Source:
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: ELB_CUSTOM_SECURITY_POLICY_SSL_CHECK
    Type: AWS::Config::ConfigRule
EOT
```

This should be fixed to look like the following (note that it is `Properties` instead of `properties`):

```
resource "aws_config_conformance_pack" "conformancepack" {
  name = "conformancepact"

  template_body = <<EOT
Resources:
  ElbCustomSecurityPolicySslCheck:
    Properties:
      ConfigRuleName: elb-custom-security-policy-ssl-check
      InputParameters:
        sslProtocolsAndCiphers: "${var.elb_custom_security_policy_ssl_check}"
      Scope:
        ComplianceResourceTypes:
        - AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
      Source:
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: ELB_CUSTOM_SECURITY_POLICY_SSL_CHECK
    Type: AWS::Config::ConfigRule
EOT
}
```

However, based on the terraform documentation note the following:

> The account must have a Configuration Recorder with proper IAM permissions before the Conformance Pack will successfully create or update. See also the [`aws_config_configuration_recorder` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/config_configuration_recorder).

Comment: Excellent observation. I updated and it deployed successfully

Answer (score 1):

There is a spelling error in your conformancePack configuration ConifigRuleName instead of ConfigRuleName

Comment: Good catch but the deployment still fails